# How to overcome a bug involving writing to a static field in an instance method in JSF?

Tags: java, jenkins, jsf-2.2, static-variables

I know very well that writing to a `static variable in an instance method` is a bad practice. (since it will be manipulated by all the instances).

We are using ***Jenkins*** for build purposes.
I haven't written the code but have been recruited into the team for fixing the bugs.

There is a method inside the class ***TreeBean.java***

```
TreeNode getRootNode(){
    // construst the tree here, creating nodes and appending child, all that stuff
        // here we have this static variable
        MyOverviewBean.tempNewvalue = MyInterface.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
}
```

where

```
String DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = "10";
```

in ***MyInterface.java***

Now we have this ***static variable*** `MyOverviewBean.tempNewvalue` that will be assign a value of `10` so that as soon as a user clicks on one of the nodes, he is shown ***10 records***.

At the bottom of the JSF page which I am talking about, there is a drop down list that allows user to select the no. of records. Currently, he has 4 options

```
10
50
100
1000
```

***MyOverviewBean.java***
A ***value change listener*** is there to take care of this above thing ***(No. of records selected by user)***.

There are 2 methods that does the backward processing.
***It changes the value of that static variable which I am talking about.***

```
public void changeRowsCount(ValueChangeEvent anEvent){
      String tmpNewVal = null;
      tmpNewVal = ((String) anEvent.getNewValue());
      tempNewvalue= tmpNewVal;  // here the new value is assigned
      setRowCountValue(tempNewvalue);
      ...
}
```

and the other method being,
***This method handles the page count.***

```
public void initializeRowCount(String compId){
     setRowCount(tempNewvalue);

     ...
}
```

How can I remove this static variable?

I have tried it with ***assigning the new value to a local variable inside the changeRowCount*** but then I failed to pass it to the other method ***initializeRowCount*** which is currently happening due to the ***static variable***. 
Kindly help.

I also tried to make the static variable simply an instance variable and then access that instance variable in TreeNode getRootNode(){

```
// below alternative as implemented by me.
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
MyOverviewBean myOverviewBean=    
            context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#
            {myOverviewBean}", MyOverviewBean.class);

// so now this code
MyOverviewBean.tempNewvalue = MyInterface.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
becomes 
myOverviewBean.tempNewvalue = MyInterface.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
```

but in vain, as ***no. of records selected by user are not in sync with the no.of records shown in the datatable***.

Kindly suggest something to me.